"not equal" condition causing the filter to generate an "N/A" error
I have the following formula in one of my Google Sheets which has worked for years.
=iferror(filter('Flag Duplicates 1'!A2:N,
    not(isblank('Flag Duplicates 1'!A2:A)),
                'Flag Duplicates 1'!Q2:Q<>"Duplicate",
                'Flag Duplicates 1'!O2:O=P1),"")

Suddenly today the Q2:Q<>"Duplicate" is generating an error and causing the filter to generate an "N/A" error (no records found).
Has Google changed anything recently?  I use this approach to eliminate duplicates in many of my sheets.
The filter works if I take out the <> section and I have not been able to find a reference to this issue online.

can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result? your formula is valid and without syntax errors

Did you check that you have value Duplicate in range 'Flag Duplicates 1'!Q2:Q?
